# AngularJS ui router - authentication resolving results in stalled request

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

For some reason the combination of Angular's ui router and authentication doesn't work for me. 
The app state is first to be resolved by logging in, but when it is resolved the GET request of the template view is stalled.

The code I supply is based on [Angular.js Authentication with UI-Router](http://blog.thejsj.com/angular-js-authentication-with-ui-router/)

The idea is that when the user is not logged in the state is changed to *login*. When the user has successfully logged in, the state should change to *app*.
The authentication promise should be resolved before the *InitiateAppController* is loaded.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  var authenticated = ['$q', 'SessionFactory', function ($q, SessionFactory) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    SessionFactory.isLoggedIn(false)
      .then(function (isLoggedIn) {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          deferred.resolve("logged in");
        } else {
          deferred.reject("You need to log in.");
        }
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  }];

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/login-bar.html',
      controller: 'SessionController',
      url: '/login'
    })
    .state('app', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/menu-bar.html',
      controller: 'InitiateAppController',
      url: '/',
      resolve: {
        authenticated: authenticated
      }
    });
});
```

The *SessionFactory* is used to check whether a user is logged in or not.

```
app.factory('SessionFactory', function ($resource, $http, $state) {
  return {
    login: $resource('api/login/', {}, {
      save: {
        method: 'POST'
      }
    }),
    isLoggedIn: function(redirectToLogin) {
      return $http.get('api/loggedin')
        .then(function (res) {
          var user = res.data; //Either 0 or a user object
          if (user !== '0') {
            return user;
          }
          if (redirectToLogin) {
            return $state.go('login');
          }
          return false;
        });
    }
  }
});
```

The following piece of code (summarized) is executed when the user clicks the login button in the *login_bar.html* view:

```
$scope.login = function () {
  var user = {};
  user.username = $scope.login.username;
  user.password = $scope.login.password;
  SessionFactory.login.save(user,
    function (data) {
      $state.go('app');
    },
    function (err) {
    });
}
```

Now what happens is the following:

1. User goes to localhost:3000/
2. GET *menu_bar.html* request is stalled
3. State change to *login* and _login_bar.html is loaded.
4. User logs in and the **$stateChangeStart* event for the *app* state is started.
5. Nothing happens for 2 minutes and only then the *menu*\bar.html and its controller is loaded.

[image: Stalled request for 2 minutes.]

Basically I am curious the know how to solve this problem. I want the state to change to *login* when the user is not logged in and have it change to *app* after login immediately.

Thank you in advance!

(I am happy to supply more information)